Manhwa where the female lead is transferred into a Korean girl's body in the modern world and learns modern medicine
I'm looking for a manhwa where the female lead is transferred into a Korean girl's body in the modern world and learns modern medicine.
The black-haired, illegitimate female lead (FL) was ignored by her family and white-haired husband. She gets transferred into a modern Korean girl with a loving family. She almost mastered her modern medical.
That Korean girl's soul gets transferred into the FL's body. The girl tried to get attention from her husband, but it didn't work. Afterwards, she asked for a divorce, but got kicked out of the house by her bitch mother-in-law, who abused her (both the FL and the Korean girl) physically and mentally. Of course, her husband didn't give a shit.
His red-haired brother was trying to protect a child. The FL cured that child by making a contract for divorce. She got a chance to cure the crown princess and secured quite a reputation as a doctor for curing an incurable disease. The princess had short yellow hair with red patches on her face and whole body. She used to cover her face all the time and had to bathe three times a day, due to the intense hotness caused by the disease.

Sounds like you're describing a manhwa here. Is that correct?

"...had to bathe three times a day, due to intense hotness caused by the disease." Yes, that sounds about right for this genre of manga/manhwa.

yaaah! i forgot the name but it's still ongoing, i am desperately searching for it. It's a korean manhwa

This is likely Post-Possession Damage Control. It is licensed by Tapas.

Seven years ago, Kanna was thrown into the body of a Korean girl named Joohwa. She had everything in her new life—a loving family, a great boyfriend, a hard-won medical license, even her own clinic! But that all changes when she's suddenly swapped back one day. Just as she's been in Joohwa's body, Joohwa has been in hers... and she's left Kanna's life a mess! First things first, she's going to divorce her cold husband, Duke Silvian Valentino. After that? Revenge on everyone who's wronged her.


The story is a two-part isekai; the protagonist is a character in another world and swaps souls with a modern Korean girl. She was abused in her original world but finds happiness and pursues a career in medicine while in Korea. She is just as abruptly sent back to her original world.
The white haired husband is shown in the first chapter,

Kanna has no idea who he is; the marriage was done while the Korean girl was in her body.
I did not find the scene with protecting a girl or the princess while skimming chapters, but she does use her modern medical knowledge in the original world to treat her wounds using herbs taken from a greenhouse and to identify a poison mixed in with some tea.
